# calling a python module that reads a file

Tags: python, package

so my program import a utils that reads a file in the same directory as the utils. However, this utils function can be called from different files from different directory.

```
Project
|
|-module_1: 
     |__ init __.py
     | file.py <--- calls util.load_file() 
|module_2:
     | __ init __.py 
     | utils.py <---- load_file() path used 'file.txt' 
     | file.txt
```

what is this thing called ? I couldn't even search for it. tried package managment, expanding path ...etc

Comment: I not sure the issue you are facing, I guess its about import/use load file fun in module_2 in module1. 
In file.py,     from module_2.utils imprt load_file

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you want to know what `utils.py` is called or how you can ensure that `utils.py` reads a file from the directory in which it is located?

Comment: how you can ensure that utils.py reads a file from the directory in which it is located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__file__` contains the path to the current file. Check it with `print(__file__)`.

[`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) from Pythons standard library can be used to construct an absolute path to the data file.

```
import pathlib

print(pathlib.Path(__file__))
print(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent)
print(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / 'file.txt')
```

You can now open your file like this:

```
filepath = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / 'file.txt'
with open(filepath) as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```